# How to get all value from a list li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sample code:

```
<ul id="classList">
<li class="visibleLayer" data-attr="1">Class 1</li>
<li class="" data-attr="2">Class 2</li>
<li class="visibleLayer" data-attr="3">Class 3</li>
<li class="" data-attr="4">Class 4</li>
</ul>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="getList();">Get</a>
```

my javascript:

```
function getList() {
   classAdder = document.getElementById('classList');
   ...
}
```

=> How to get all ***data-attr*** have class are ***visibleLayer***

Comment: jQuery, javascript or are both okay?

Answer (score 1):

You need `$.fn.map`, `$.fn.get` and some basic selectors. `[attr-name[=attr-value]]` is CSS selector for attributes and `.className` is the CSS selector for classes.

We combine them both and use `$.fn.map` and `$.fn.get` to return the array of attributes.

```
var attrs = $('[data-attr].visibleLayer').map(function(){
   return $(this).data("attr");
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll()`  to get the element collection and then iterate it with `for` loop to get attribute `data-attr`.

```
function getList(){
    var li = document.querySelectorAll('#classList li[class=visibleLayer]')
    for(var i = 0; i < li.length ; i++)
       console.log(li[i].getAttribute('data-attr'))

}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kpwxy0wy/)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the `ul` and check if the children have the required class.

```
$('#classList').children('li').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("visibleLayer")) {
        console.log($(this).data("attr"));
    }
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q023dz82/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `filter` to filter out the li with required class

```
 $('#classList li[class=visibleLayer]').filter(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('data-attr')); //gives 1 and 3
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getList() {
if($('#classList .visibleLayer').length) {
    $('#classList .visibleLayer').each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('data-attr'));
    });
}
```

}

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vsok/7ptq3677/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getList(){
  var phrases = [];
  $('#classList').each(function(){      
    var phrase = '';
    $(this).find('.visibleLayer').each(function(){      
      phrase = $(this).attr("data-attr");
      alert(phrase)
    });  
    phrases.push(phrase);
  }); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Test Page </title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
 </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="classList">
      <li class="visibleLayer" data-attr="1">Class 1</li>
      <li class="" data-attr="2">Class 2</li>
      <li class="visibleLayer" data-attr="3">Class 3</li>
      <li class="" data-attr="4">Class 4</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="getList();">Get</a>

  </body>
</html>
```